# On Left and right click events change each input value

Tags: javascript

So on Left click it alerts the value `0` On right click it alerts the value `2`. Instead of alerts, I want on each button click to change the input value to the following:

> When left click the input clicked should show the value 0
>   
>   When right click the input clicked should show the value 1

```js
 function WhichButton(event) {
       var a = event.button;
       if(a === 0 )alert("Button clicked: "+a);//when clicked button value should be 0
       if(a === 2 )alert("Button clicked: "+a);//when clicked button value should be 1
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" onmousedown="WhichButton(event)" >
<input type="text" onmousedown="WhichButton(event)" >
<input type="text" onmousedown="WhichButton(event)" >
<input type="text" onmousedown="WhichButton(event)" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply edit your `WhichButton` function to change the `value` attribute of the targeted element.

*EDIT : As requested in the comments, I replaced `onmousedown` by `onmouseup` so that the event fires at the end of the mouse event. I added `event.target.blur()` to force lose the focus. Finally I added `oncontextmenu="return false;"` on the inputs to prevent the context menu from showing up.*

```js
function WhichButton(event) {
  var a = event.button;
  if (a === 0) event.target.value = 0;
  if (a === 2) event.target.value = 1;
  event.target.blur();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onmouseup="WhichButton(event)" oncontextmenu="return false;">
<input type="text" onmouseup="WhichButton(event)" oncontextmenu="return false;">
<input type="text" onmouseup="WhichButton(event)" oncontextmenu="return false;">
<input type="text" onmouseup="WhichButton(event)" oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

Comment: one question do you know what is the vertical bar called next to the typing text ? I want to remove that from the input

Comment: @GragasIncoming I edited my answer to do just that. I changed `onmousedown` to `onmouseup` so that it only triggers at the end of the mouse event, and added `event.target.blur()` to force lose focus.

Comment: also use  `window.oncontextmenu = function () {  return false; }` to prevent browser right click and it will be a great solution :)

Comment: @GragasIncoming I added that too.

Answer (score 0):

Right click has index `2`, not `1`:

[image]

So if you want to alert `1` on right click, you can just hardcode `1` in this case, like this:

```js
function WhichButton(event) {
  var a = event.button;
  if(a === 0 ) event.target.value = 0;
  if(a === 2 ) event.target.value = 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onmousedown="WhichButton(event)" >
<input type="text" onmousedown="WhichButton(event)" >
<input type="text" onmousedown="WhichButton(event)" >
<input type="text" onmousedown="WhichButton(event)" >
```

For more info about `MouseEvent.button`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

Comment: @Zenoo, if you mean *"I want on each button click to change the input value to the following"*, I'll update my answer in few minutes

Comment: What's the use of your `inputs` variable, then?

Comment: @Zenoo what do you mean?

Comment: `var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');` is useless in your code.

Comment: @Zenoo, sorry, just forgot to clean up